# How can I create a third-party shortcut that allows copy/duplicate?

Tags: google-drive-api

My application creates documents in Google Drive as third-party shortcuts (MIME type `application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk`) as [recommended](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/third-party-shortcuts) for the Drive SDK.

However it appears that this type of document in Drive cannot be copied with the usual `right-click - Make a Copy` from the Drive folder listing, and in Google Classroom if you try to assign the file with "Make a copy for each student" it reports an error (with the world's most useless error message:  "There was an error. Please try again").

Is there any way to mark a third-party shortcut as legal to copy?